# Unable to get item position to dismiss listitem

Tags: android, android-listview, swipe

I am using Roman Nurik's `SwipeListViewTouchListener` in my app to dismiss the list items.
This is what I am doing:

```
SwipeListViewTouchListener touchListener2 =
                new SwipeListViewTouchListener(
                    lv,
                    new SwipeListViewTouchListener.OnSwipeCallback() {
                       @Override
                      public void onSwipeLeft(ListView listView, int [] reverseSortedPositions) { 
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LEFT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                      }

                      @Override
                     public void onSwipeRight(ListView listView, int [] reverseSortedPositions) {

                        }
                 },
                 true, // example : left action = dismiss
                 true); // example : right action without dismiss animation

        lv.setOnTouchListener(touchListener2); 
        lv.setOnScrollListener(touchListener2.makeScrollListener());
```

Now my problem is how do I remove the dismissed item from the list (something like

```
customAdapter.remove(position);
```

and notify the adapter like

```
customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: you answered your question. Remove the item from the adapter and call  notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: what's problem if u have adapter just do whatever u want.

Comment: @keshav But I am unable to get the value of position in the toouchlistiner2.

Comment: are you getting data from db

Comment: @Sparkplug what is your customAdapter? is it extending BaseAdpter or ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
public void onSwipeLeft(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LEFT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (reverseSortedPositions != null && reverseSortedPositions.length>0) {
        for (int i : reverseSortedPositions) {
            customAdapter.remove(i);
        }
        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Now it is working as it was intended to.